# get sub array key php

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i have an array:

```
Array
( 
[47] => Array
    (
        [name] => 3543 good
        [price] => 100.0000
        [image] => data/hp_1.jpg
        [discount] => 
        [stock_status] => 
        [weight_class] => kg
    )

[28] => Array
    (
        [name] => HTC Touch HD
        [price] => 100.0000
        [image] => data/htc_touch_hd_1.jpg
        [discount] => 
        [stock_status] => 
        [weight_class] => g
    )

[41] => Array
    (
        [name] => iMac
        [price] => 100.0000
        [image] => data/imac_1.jpg
        [discount] => 
        [stock_status] => 
        [weight_class] => kg
    )

[40] => Array
    (
        [name] => iPhone
        [price] => 101.0000
        [image] => data/iphone_1.jpg
        [discount] => 
        [stock_status] => 
        [weight_class] => kg
    )
)
```

i need the sub array key (47 ,28  etc) as it is my product id

I'm running a foreach loop to get the details and assigning to a new array e.g. `'name' => $result['name']` but can't figure out how to target the product id.

Comment: Please complete this old question by including your coding attempt and exact desired output array based on the sample input.  Improving old questions role models good posting behaviors to new users (and increases the chances of your question being helpful / upvotevoteworthy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can assign the key to a variable in your foreach loop:

```
foreach($array as $id => $result) {
    $item = array('name' => $result['name'], 'id' => $id);
}
```

Comment: What about if I want to get the keys of sub-arrays of an array.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over it as a associative array with a key value pair.

```
foreach($array as $key=>$value) {
   echo $key; // this is what you need, if I got you right
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`foreach` allows you to iterate over not just the values but also the keys in this way:

```
foreach($items as $key => $value)
{
    ...
}
```

In your case it would look like:

```
foreach($results as $id => $result)
{
    $item = array('name' => $result['name'], 'id' => $id, ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the key variable to your `foreach` loop, like so:

```
foreach( $array as $product_id => $result)
    echo $product_id . ' costs ' . $result['price'] . "\n";
```